# httpd slowing down due to lots of CLOSE_WAIT's

Tags: linux, apache

My web server is getting bogged down by lots of tcp CLOSE_WAIT's. I restart httpd and the server starts running fine again. But within half a day, it slows down to a stop. I do a `netstat` and see tons of `CLOSE_WAITS`. Is this expected behavior or is something wrong? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its meant to be like that Apache should be reusing when it needs, It may not be the cause of slow downs. What are you serving ? And if its dynamic how are you serving it ? (CGI / Apache Module etc )